# The storage setting in /etc/systemd/journald.conf is commented out but the action is still being performed

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-journald

`#Storage=auto` was set in `journald.conf` file and there was no `/var/log/journal` directory. Once I created that directory manually, `ryslog` started writing to it. What's the point of the line being commented out if the action is still being performed? All the lines in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` are commented out. Does that mean that all the lines are active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that does not mean it.

In general, what a line means in a config file is 100% up to the program reading and interpreting it.

In general, I'd expect commenting something out to mean "ignore this". So it's as if it's not written there.

If a setting is not specified, the default setting is used.

`auto` is the default for `Storage=` (see `man journald.conf`).

So, all this is working as specified.

Comment: +1.  Also, while it's by no means universal, it's not uncommon for programs to come with config files that have some or all of their default settings commented out.  Partly as documentation of current/default settings, and partly as an example of what can be configured.